# MS access SELECT INTO in vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm having some issues with some functionality of my application. There is a particular instance where I have an instance of a 'pending class' on a form for an administrator to review. The form is populated with students associated with this pending class. After their grades are finished, I have a button at the footer that will delete this class from my 'pending' table and add the grades to all of the students. This works.
However, I want to essentially copy this pending class, which just has the class name, date, and teacher to a completed class table before it's deleted from pending. Since no data about this class other than the primary key(class number) persists throughout this form, I can't populate the other fields(class name, date) of the row into my completed class table.

I am trying a "SELECT INTO" operation in VBA to get these values. It's going like this:

```
   dim cname as String
   dim classdate as Date
   dim pid as integer
   dim teacher as String
   dim qry as String

    pid = [Forms]![frmClasses]![txtID]

   qry = "Select className INTO cname FROM tblPending WHERE tblPending.id = " & " ' " & pid & " ' " & ";"

   db.execute qry
   debug.print qry
   debug.print cname
```

From here, I do the same operations for each other variable, build my INSERT query, and execute it. The problem is-- my select into's are not working. Debug.print shows that the local variables were never initialized from the SELECT INTO statement. Any thoughts?

Comment: That is a make table query, I reckon you want an append query. I really do not think your ID is text. If pid is null (empty) then it seems likely that [Forms]![frmClasses]![txtID] is empty. Try using the Me keyword and see what control names it comes up with -- Me. will bring up intellisense.

Comment: I can't use the Me keyword in this case. Instead of opening the form with a param, I am using a field from the previous form. The field with txtID (a textbox with the relevent class's ID) is on the previous form. Also, this part is working as intended. The query printed out is "Select ClassName INTO cName FROM tblPending WHERe tblPending.id = '17';" I also tried removing the single quotes around the id criteria, as it is an integer, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Depending on which selection I made from the previous form, I get the correct corresponding class ID

Comment: ^ it is "SELECT ClassName INTO cName FROM tblPending WHERE tblPending.id = '17';"  if I build the query by having qry = "SELECT ClassName INTO  " & cName & " WHERE tblPending.ID = " & "'" & pid & "'" & ";" I get "SELECT ClassName INTO   WHERE tblPending.ID = '17';"

Comment: I'm just assuming at this point that access VBA doesn't work the same as PL/SQL when it comes to "SELECT INTO". Do you have another recommended way to basically copy a row of one table into another table, knowing just the PK of that row?

Comment: I'm worked around it for now by just adding hidden controls to hold the values, but I'd still like to know how to do this operation with SELECT INTO, if anyone knows.

Comment: SELECT INTO creates a table, what you want is INSERT INTO, which appends to a table. Also, add  `db.execute qry, dbFailOnerror` - your query will fail if the table exists and you will not get a warning otherwise.

Comment: So SELECT INTO is completely different in Access than Oracle? In Oracle and PL/SQL, you can select a row into a variable OR a table. In Access can you not select into a variable?

Comment: In MS Access SELECT INTO creates a table, like t-sql: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: In MS Access, you can use `DLookup()` to "*select into a variable*" http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx You may find other "domain functions" useful: DMin(); DMax(); DAvg(); etc.

Comment: @hansup Thanks, that appears to be the equivalent of what I was trying to do with "SELECT INTO"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, having all classes in one table and just setting a "NotPending" or "Completed" column would be better.
Having two identical tables for classes and moving values from one into the other to indicate status changes is bad database design.

---

If you *really* need to do this by using two tables and copying rows, then you need [an `INSERT INTO` query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (and [not `SELECT INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934%28v=office.12%29)), as already mentioned by Remou in the comments, because `SELECT INTO` creates a new table (or overwrites an existing one with the same name, if already there).

The syntax for `INSERT INTO` looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO CompletedClassTable (ClassName, Teacher)
SELECT ClassName, Teacher FROM tblPending WHERE id = 123
```

---

And finally, you asked this in a comment:

> So SELECT INTO is completely different in Access than Oracle? In Oracle and PL/SQL, you can select a row into a variable OR a table. In Access can you not select into a variable?

To load a row into a variable, you need to use a [Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177501%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Example code to load your query into a Recordset and output the `ClassName` field:

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblPending WHERE id = 123")
If Not RS.EOF Then
    Debug.Print RS("classname")
End If
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
```

Comment: I feel that my intended use for 'select into' is misunderstood.My intention was to SELECT INTO to get a value from a row and assigning it to a variable in VBA from a table where I know the PK, much like in PL/SQL.Iterating through a RS seems to be the comparative solution for Access as you mentioned. As far as database design goes,the pending table and the completed table are not the EXACT same. My completed table has all of the fields of the pending table with the addition of a couple fields. In this case, I view a completed class and a class that's in progress(pending) as different entities

Comment: I'm not sure if my question was ambiguous or my intentions were unclear, but I'll go ahead and mark this as 'answered' --  it is NOT possible to use 'SELECT INTO' in VBA to assign a value from a row to a variable. To accomplish this, I would need to Open a recordSet of the necessary query. Is this an appropriate summary in your opinion?

Comment: I don't know Oracle and PL/SQL, so I can't tell how it works there, except from what you said. To assign a value from a row to a variable, you need a `Recordset` or, if you need just ONE value, [you can use `DLookup`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx). But if you just want to copy a row to another table, I'd use an `INSERT INTO` query. IMO that's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Sounds good, Thanks for the input. I'll go ahead and accept this and consider it answered

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to retrieve a text value, `className`, from `tblPending` where `tblPending.id` matches the value found in your text box, `txtID`, and store that text value in a string variable named `cname`.

If that interpretation is correct, you needn't bother with a query and recordset.  Just use the [DLookup Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx) to retrieve the value, similar to this untested code sample.

```
Dim cname As String
Dim pid As Integer
Dim strCriteria As String
pid = [Forms]![frmClasses]![txtID]
strCriteria = "id = " & pid
cname = Nz(DLookup("className", "tblPending", strCriteria), vbNullString)
Debug.Print "cname: '" & cname & "'"
```

Notes:

1. I assumed the data type of the `id` field in `tblPending` is numeric.  If it is actually text data type, change `strCriteria` like this:

   strCriteria = "id = '" & pid & "'"
2. `DLookup()` returns Null if no match found.  Since we are assigning the function's return value to a string variable, I used `Nz()` to convert Null to an empty string.  Alternatively, you could declare cname As Variant (so that it can accept a Null value) and get rid of `Nz()`.

Comment: This also works. I implemented my form using dLookup after you posted your comment to my question^ and it works (my code is similar to the code you provided with this answer). Before, I was using a hidden control on a previous form to store the variables -- an ugly workaround since I didn't know about DLookup(). Thanks for making me aware of it, I'm sure I will use it often in the future, as I am more comfortable with coding my insertions,updates, and deletes in VBA rather than using the default operations provided by wizards.

Comment: Once it dawned on me that you really wanted to SELECT INTO *a variable*, `DLookup()` emerged as the simple solution.  When I first read your question, I misinterpreted the goal as storing a SELECTed value in a table (new or existing).

Comment: I think that is what Remou and Christian thought also. I am used to using SELECT INTO to get values from a table into a local variable in PL/SQL. This is where the confusion stemmed from. I didn't want to 'SELECT INTO', I wanted to know what the Access equivalent of that operation is. DLookup is the answer that was looking for.